# Retrieve refernce from graph series

Tags: vba, excel, graph, charts

I have two master sheets (templates) in excel that contains a format of data and graphs. 
With VBA I created a code to copy these master sheets automatically.
But I have some problems getting the graphs getting the data from the correct sheets.

The graph.collectionseries.Value in the master sheet has a reference like:

```
"=Master_sheet!A1:B2"
```

Every time I copy and adept this master sheets I need to change all references

```
"=Master_sheet!A1:B2" --> "=LocationX!A1:B2"  or "=LocationY!A1:B2"
```

My approach that doesn't work is as follows:

`Value_old =  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection().Value`   <-- This returns a string value, not s 
                                                        string with the reference!

```
Value_new = Replace(Value_Old, "Master_sheet", " LocationX")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection().Value = Value_new
```

How can I get the reference from SeriesCollection.Value or name?

Thanks.

Comment: `1.`Jort which version of Excel are you using? `2.` Do you want to get the source range address - such that where the data for series collection comes from? or `3.` Do you want to get the value? sorry it's a bit not clear what you really need?

Comment: 1. excel 2010 2. Yes 
3. No I want the reference tekst like the example "=Master_sheet!A1:B2"
Now I only get the value from the cells Master_sheet!A1:B2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather not clear what you are trying to achieve. But if you want to get the `Chart.SeriesCollection` source data address try this please:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).FormulaLocal
```

So if you need to get for each series, then you have to loop through..

Comment: Jort you are better off if [@Jon Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/QuickChartVBA.html) had seen this question. +1 Good question though.